# vagrant Vagrantfile mount point ignored

Tags: vagrant

I have a Vagrantfile as below running under `libvirt`. When the box boots, the project directory is mounted under "`/vagrant`" not "`/path/to/source`". It works fine on another machine under VirtualBox.

Any ideas? Symlinking `/vagrant` to the actual place I want the mount is hacky.

`vagrant up --debug` shows that it isn't even attempting it. The port forwarding works OK though.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mybox"

  file = File.open("#{Dir.home}/.mybox_key", "rb")
  key = file.read

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/path/to/source/", type: "nfs" 

end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running an older version of Vagrant that doesn't support this option (e.g. 1.3.5), it may fail silently instead of trying to setup the NFS share. Ensure you're running at least Vagrant 1.5.1.

Comment: It does support it, in the end I just ditched nfs exports